# Is tomcat empty project directory when redeploying a war?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I have a web project using third-party rich text editor. It support image upload and uploaded images are stored in project folder like ./myeditor/uploadimg by default. If I replace the project war with a newer version, will tomcat empty the image folder? If so, can I force tomcat not do it? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If the upload directory is within tomcat's `webapps` directory, especially within the app that you're redeploying: yes, most likely it'll be removed

The way around this is to put it elsewhere, in a directory under *your* control, not under tomcat's.